# Is there option to add file to the project in visual studio?

Tags: c#, file

I'm new to c# and I only know the basics of it. I have some data in json file and I want it to be added to my visual studio without specifying the path of it (so other people don't need to change file location when they get my program). After building the project I want the file to be automatically in the project folder somehow.

Comment: They don't have to change the location. Project file paths are relative. If you want other people to get that file though, you need to include it in the Git repository. Adding a path to a project file won't add it to the repo. Besides, JSON is content, not source.

Comment: MSDN [Add files to a solution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/creating-solutions-and-projects?view=vs-2019#add-files-to-a-solution), "_To add an item to a solution, on the context (right-click) menu of the solution node in Solution Explorer, select Add > New Item, or Add > Existing Item._"

Comment: Hi, probably you should read this topic here - it explains a lot ;-)
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/solutions-and-projects-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2019

Comment: Adding a data file to a project doesn't mean it's going to be used, published or deployed. A file with local settings shouldn't be deployed to production after all. You can specify that a file is `Content` if you want it to be published. If you want to copy the file to the output folder *without* making it a content file, you can change the `Copy to Output Folder` setting to `Copy if Newer` from the default `Never`

Answer (score 1):

Including file in the project and moving it to the output dir automatically are different actions.

To add an existing file to project, right click your project and select **"Add Existing Item"**. Then open file properties (right click the file => properties) and set **Copy to Output Directory** to **Copy Always**